# Bluetooth adapter not found Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, chrome-book

I know this has been asked a lot, but I have tried almost every possible answer and it still isn't working. I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus C300 chromebook through crouton, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the bluetooth to work. The bluetooth adapter is not being recognized by Ubuntu. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I seem to be having a similar problem getting the bluetooth to work with Arch on my Chromebook C201 (armv7)